# Отступы сверху и снизу в ячейке таблицы

Tags: html, css

Вкратце код выглядит так:

```css
.top-icons, .bottom-icons
{
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<td>
  <div>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    <img scr="smile"/>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
  <div class="top-icons"></div>
  <div class="bottom-icons"></div>
  </div>
<td>
```

[image: Картинка проблемы]

**Мне нужно, чтобы смайлик не ограничивался этими отступами в ячейке. Чтобы он почти касался границ ячейки.**

Я уже пробовала добавлять `padding:0; cellpadding:0`, колдовала над позиционированием элементов, меняла `display` у `img`, но ничего не помогло! `line-height` тоже применяла. Ничего!

Comment: Предоставленного Вами кода не достаточно. Проблема может быть как в css, так и в html. Может быть из-за иконок до/после смайлика. Вобщем нужен полный код.

Comment: таки почему вы думаете что это отступы у ячейки, а не у картинки?

Comment: Какой размер у картинки смайлика в исходном виде?

Answer (score 1):

всем ячейкам `position: relative`, a `<img>` absolute и дайте им `w:100% + h: auto`, или же все равно календарь будет работать на js. дайте класс active ячейке которая должна быть и иконку сделайте на этот класс b`ackground:url(icon.png) и background-size: contain`